# echo yes or no if results are found from images.google.com

Tags: html, google-image-search

I am currently working on a html/script that uses google's image search to simply return a yes or no if results are found, I think I can handle parsing the information from the user (URL of an image) into the google image search URL string but I can't determine what variable or how I could get my script to recognize if results were found or not... I apologize for my script below as the only language I've used before is ASP but have very little experience:

```
   <?php 
$action=$_REQUEST['action']; 
if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */ 
    { 
    ?> 
    <form  action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit"> 
    Link to image:<br> 
    <input name="name"/><br>
    </form> 
    <?php 
    }  
else                /* send the submitted data */ 
    { 
    $name=$_REQUEST['name'];  
    if (($name==""))
        { 
        echo "Please Enter a URL"; 
        } 
    else{         
        echo "https://www.google.ca/searchbyimage?site=search&image_url=$name&as_sitesearch=jamesmorgan.ca&safe=images"; 
        } 
    }   
?>
```

I'm also aware that my secondary echo commands does nothing, I was thinking maybe I could use the header command to just redirect them to the google image website with the results but ideally I'd like the script to recognize whether or not there are results, I feel like I might be approaching this all wrong, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starter, you might want to check if `$_REQUEST['action']` is set in line 1 first, such as `isset()` function.

As for handling the feedback, you may try looking into [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/%20%22%20PHP%20Simple%20HTML%20DOM%20Parser) - which basically allows you to get the HTML content from a specific page, and you can process it yourself and etc.

Hope this helps! Good Luck!